# Only depth info from kinect

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using openni_kinect with Diamondback on Ubuntu 10.04. Does anyone know if there is a way to capture just depth data for further analysis ?

From the RGBDSLAM tutorials, after running 'roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch ' I could save point cloud data from the rviz screen as a .ply file (which has x,y,z,r,g,b entries for all points) to see it in something like Meshlab. The problem in this is that the file is really large (10-15 MB) and it is difficult to segregate and analyze just x,y,z data from this.

By the way, what I am trying to do is capture the depth info around at certain frequency and estimate the dynamics of the environment progressively from all the frames captured. Any help is really appreciated

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11154/only-depth-info-from-kinect/) by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To record data in ROS you should use [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1